# YII query Builder wont show results

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, yii, where-clause

I have a problem using two different sintax of yii query builder
Using this, works perfectly (but i cannot use variables inside the SQL)

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;

$sql='SELECT id_activo, nom_activo, valor_activo, cod_amenaza, tipo_activo, deg_amenaza, 
frec_amaneza FROM activo, amenazas WHERE amenazas.activos_amenaza ILIKE "%"|| activo.tipo_activo ||"%" AND id_activo=1';
$query = str_replace('"',"'",$sql);

$command = $connection->createCommand("$query");
$rows = $command->queryAll();
```

Using this wont show anything

```
$i=1;
$rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('id_activo, nom_activo, valor_activo, cod_amenaza, tipo_activo, deg_amenaza, frec_amaneza')
->from('activo, amenazas')
->where('amenazas.activos_amenaza LIKE :substr', array(':substr' => '%activo.tipo_activo%'))
->andWhere('id_activo=:id', array(':id'=>$i))
->queryAll();
```

if i remove the where condition with the LIKE works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that '%activo.tipo_activo%' is not treated as data from database but just as plain string.

You can rewrite join condition like this:
    `$rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('id_activo, nom_activo, valor_activo, cod_amenaza, tipo_activo, deg_amenaza, frec_amaneza')
    ->from('activo')
    ->join('amenazas', "amenazas.activos_amenaza LIKE '%'||activo.tipo_activo||'%' ")

    ->where('id_activo=:id', array(':id'=>$i))
    ->queryAll();`